# What is the name for google's information summary box (pic inside)? Is there an api to access it from a google search?

Tags: google-search, api, screen-scraping

Example of what I'd like to access:

[image]

Just wondering if I could write something that'll query google with a search string and if the summary box returns, fetch only that, otherwise fetch the first few links. I think this is called "screen scraping"

Hope I'm within scope of the rules, not that experienced using this site or APIs at all, but I figured setting goals and hitting them is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

According to search engine watch, it's called a [google answer box](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/opinion/2414342/google-answer-boxes-the-what-why-and-how). There is a google API called freebase. However, it was retired june 30, so there will no longer be updates to the API itself.

[Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview)

[why was freebased closed?](https://plus.google.com/109936836907132434202/posts/bu3z2wVqcQc)